# How to upload and encode (base64) a file in webservice using Jmeter

Tags: encoding, jmeter, base64, jmeter-plugins

I am new to Jmeter and I need to upload a file and then encrypt the file using base64.

I am able to encode the filename and file path to base64, however I need to both upload and then encrypt the file (base64).

I attempted to use the jmeter custom extension to encode the file, however it encoded the file.

Any ideas on how I can upload the file (text/plain or text/csv or application/excel) and then encode (base64) the file.

Is it possible to specify filetostring function in jmeter ans then encode the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [__FileToString()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) functions combination like:

```
${__base64Encode(${__FileToString(/path/to/your_file)})}
```

You can install `__base64Encode()` function as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Functions Plugins Manager]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I came up with the same solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I managed to resolve the issue. I used the same custom jmeter functions and the __fileToString() function.